# What was the original plan?

Tags: plot-explanation, man-on-a-ledge

At the ending of Man on a Ledge, Nick Casidy is able to prove his innocence by showing publicly that the bad guy still has the diamond in his possession, which proves that Nick never stole it.

This only happens though after the whole plan goes completely wrong. Initially Nick's brother was supposed to steal the diamond and Nick was supposed to get away with it in his jacket. That's when he got caught.

At that point, how would he reasonably prove that he did not steal the diamond 2 years back but just that day?

Just having the diamond only proves that he stole it after all. What was the original plan before it went wrong?

Comment: I thought the plan was for them to show the diamond to the world by taking it out of the vault, not that Nick was supposed to carry it out in his jacket. I didn't think Nick was supposed to get anywhere near the diamond, but instead create the diversion so his brother and the girl friend could steal it from David Englander without getting caught ... you're right in that the plan was screwed when the diamond wasn't where it was supposed to be. I'm really not sure how that was supposed to work out, though, because it would look like he was trying to put it back or something.

Comment: I don't think they actually filmed anything when opening the vault. Not to mention that this would not prove anything either, would it? They could just have planted it there while they are in there. :)

Comment: My point about the planting part. I guess it all works out in the end :P